# Android Oreo (API 26) does not remove focus from EditText when the physical keyboard arrows are pressed

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, android-8.0-oreo

Android Oreo (API 26) does not remove the focus from EditText using the physical keyboard arrows (D_PAD_RIGHT, D_PAD_UP, etc.), but pressing ENTER (D_PAD_CENTER, keycode 66, etc ...) works. I also noticed that you can not focus on the button of the drawer (hamburger) or any other of the actionbar using the arrows in this version of the system. Does anyone know anything about this? Is it a bug or is it intentional? Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: In the version for Android TV everything works normally.

Comment: FWIW, testing on a Google Pixel with Android 8.1 and a Logitech K480 Bluetooth keyboard, the Tab key navigates between `EditText` widgets, but arrow keys do not.

Comment: True, I forgot to mention that, too. Unfortunately in my work scenario I need the arrow keys.